# AngularJS - $routeParams with $location

Tags: angularjs

I've been using the following routing

```
contractManagementApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/Clients', {
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ClientList.html',
        controller: 'ClientListCtrl'      
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Fail'
    });
]);
```

I'd like to be able to pass a parameter to that page, an id to filter by.
I've found by setting up the following code in my controller:

```
    if ($routeParams.clientId)
    {
       //Do stuff
    }
```

And pasting the following into the browser:

[linktomyhost]/Clients?clientId=107

I get the result I desire.  However when trying to redirect by code:

```
        var path='/Clients?clientId=' + $scope.clientId;
        $location.path(path);
```

This fails and takes me to my 'otherwise' condition.

Can I do this?  I'm trying to avoid having a different route condition for when I want to pass this optional filter id

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/Clients', {
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ClientList.html',
        controller: 'ClientListCtrl'      
    }).
    when('/Clients/:clientId', {
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ClientList.html',
        controller: 'ClientListCtrl'      
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Fail'
    });
```

Then you can pass in the id like so:

`[linktomyhost]/Clients/107`

If you must use query parameters, you can do this:

```
$location.search('clientId', 107).path('/Clients');
```

...and then you can retrieve the value like so:

```
var searchObject = $location.search(), // returns {clientId:107}
    clientId = searchObject.clientId;
```

Comment: I agree with your solution and personally I would do this too..But I think he knows about this approach as he said that he wants to avoid having a different route condition.

Comment: I added an alternative that uses `$location.search()`

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a built in search/filter functionality which is included in $location.

The variable $location.search() will return any data after your URL, provided you place it after a "?" question mark.

For example, the url website.com/#/module?v=2

Will return the hash {"v":"2"} when $location.search() is called.

As a result, you may use $location.search()["v"] to find the parameter at the end of the URL and store it as a variable like this:

```
var search = $location.search()["v"]; //returns 2 for v=2
```

Than simple run an if statement in your config to determine if the filter will be run or not:

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {

```
if (search == "x" )
{
    var urlPost = "_filter.html";
    else 
    urlPost = ".html";
}
```

etc.

Make sure to bind the final url to a template and controller in the config:

```
when('/module', 
{
    templateUrl: 'templates/' + urlPost,
    controller: 'MainRouteCtrl'
}).
```

Comment: I want the same template html for both, my problem is just that

    var path='/Clients?clientId=' + $scope.clientId;
    $location.path(path);

is not routing to 

    when('/Clients', {
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ClientList.html',
        controller: 'ClientListCtrl'      
    })